# Famous Question badge awarded very late

Tags: bug, badges, view-counter

My question, asked on Math.SE, linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828940/normal-curve-1-5-standard-deviations), has 12k views at the time of asking this question, but I am not awarded the Famous Question badge until a few minutes after this question was originally asked (on October 6, 2020). Why is that? I understand there may be a slight delay, even maybe a day or so, but certainly not that long?

Proof that I just got it today:

[image]

[image]

Edit: as of 10:56pm PT on October 6, 2020
[image]

Comment: I will just add that the timestamp of awarding the timestamp is also shown here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=503528

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks I have embedded it into the question itself.

Comment: That's a good question and perhaps that you will get an answer here, but it seems to me that a better place for it is [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).